# JToolBarHelper::Custom syntax

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I can't quite figure out exactly what this line does from the docs:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom( 'masterslavesync', 'save', '', 'Save', false, false );
```

Is it calling a `masterslavesync` function somewhere (controller)?  Or do I have to register it with `$this->registerTask()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is used to create custom button in the joomla admin.This code will create a save and when someone click on this button it will call masterslavesync function defined in the controller. if you want to check this just create a

```
public function masterslavesync()
  {
      echo 'I am here';
      die;
  }
```

if the text is echo properly then everything is fine....Hopefully this will help you to understand to control flow. you can also refer this http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_custom_button

Comment: ...except that it's not calling masterslavesync.  So my guess was right, I've just been handed buggy code.  Wonderful.

Also, I've read the docs on this, and said so in my question.  Linking me to them again won't help.