# Controller/JToolBar not working in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5

Relevant code:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('saveCategories', 'save', '', 'Save', false, false);
...
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="EasyBlogController">
```

According to what I can dig up from the [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JToolBarHelper/custom) and my own [previous questions,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799936/jtoolbarhelpercustom-syntax) this should call the `saveCategories()` function in the `EasyBlogController`.  I've tried setting the value to `easyblog`, `easyblog.php` (file name) as well as the current `EasyBlogController` (Class name).

Clicking on the Save button only refreshes the page.  It does not redirect, `echo` or `var_dump` any test code I put in the `saveCategories()` function.  `var_dump`ing `JRequest::getVar('controller')` and `'task'` do return the correct values.  Creating a controller object and then using `$controller->execute('task');` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values that you are going for depend obviously on the location of the controller that you are trying to call, and you have a couple options here. Typically there is a controller in the base folder of the component (likely components/com_easyblog) that is in a file called controller.php and the class name inside of it would be EasyBlogController.

There may also be a controllers folder (components/com_easyblog/controllers) that would contain controllers for particular views. Typically in this case, you would have a file called "something.php" and the class will be "EasyBlogControllerSomething". For this option, you would call this controller's saveCategories function by using the following:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('Something.saveCategories', 'save', '', 'Save', false, false);
```

Otherwise, if you just want the base controller, just don't specify the controller, since the system will default to the controller.php file. Such as the following:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('saveCategories', 'save', '', 'Save', false, false); //no hidden input after this
```

If you want to set a controller other than the default, add this html to your view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="controllerNameHere"/>
```

Comment: I figured it out yesterday, but thanks!  This is really helpful, I added a bit about setting a custom controller.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('EasyBlogController.saveCategories', 'save', '', 'Save', false, false);
```

But make sure that your controller is called EasyBlogController.php and has a function called saveCategories()

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just plain wrong.  It sets the task to "EasyBlogControllersaveCategories"